# CSS Hover: how to activate a third state equivalent to onmouseout?

Tags: button, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class, onmouseout

I'm using a cool CSS trick:
As the cursor hovers over a button a second state is activated for that hovered button -- BUT also a separate secondary state is activated for all the other buttons simultaneously.


[see dabblet live code here](http://dabblet.com/gist/9e010d3827e45d97de853e3fc89867e2)

What I want:
A CSS solution that imitates onmouseout (let's call it "hover off") to activate a third state for all the buttons simultaneously when the cursor is no longer hovering over any of the buttons.

Option 1. Ideally, during "hover off" we could change the original color of all the buttons (white) to another color (red, let's say).

Option 2. Otherwise, if we can disappear all the buttons during "hover off", that's also a good solution.

Comment: Not sure I understand. The buttons when no longer hovered should look different from never having been hovered? If that's what you want, there is no css-only solution.

Comment: Yes, I want the buttons to transition to a new state rather than returning to the original state.

Comment: OK. Like I said, no CSS-only solution. Use onmouseout.